# Webpage scrolling horizontally with only whitespace to the right

Tags: css, scrollbar, whitespace

I've been developing this site for a while and suddenly today I noticed that the horizontal scrollbar on my browser was showing and was allowing the site to be scrolled a few inches to the right, all of which consists solely of whitespace.

It's doing this on several pages, but not all.

Here is a page on which I have the issue - http://www.princewebdesigns.com/staging/gallais/our-firm.html

Here is a page on which I do not have the issue - http://www.princewebdesigns.com/staging/gallais/index.html

I've tried debugging in FireBug but I can't find any divs or elements that are causing the page to be wider. Is it possibly related to a float? It appears to be an issue in all browsers.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS - I know the nav links are not functioning, it's because I'm temporarily housing the site in my web server's staging directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css class `.bluebar h1` has a property `width: 70em;`

em should not be used to define width of elements. Your browser calculates the h1 to a font-size of 28px, which makes the .bluebar 28 x 70 = 1960px wide. For a proper explenation on em and other css units, see [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Both Firebug and Dragonfly allow you to hover the page. This is default behaviour in Dragonfly . In Firebug you can turn it on by clicking the arrow button on the top left of the firebug window. This way you can find the elements quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this bit:

```
<div class="bluebar">
```

If you change that to be `<div class="banner">` then it works okay (but obviously you now have the background graphics. On further inspection I see that... oh hang on... no point in duplicating the answer here!

*EDIT: Okay, I took too long answering this - lol! Give Benjamin the answer credit.*